# More efficient looping?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, operators

So I'm writing a simple struct to act like an Array of strings but with some handy operators and other functions that I've always wanted to see in strings. Specifically the method I'm working on right now is the / operator. **The problem is, it won't add on any remainders at the end like I want it to.**

What it's supposed to do, is take an array of strings, like `{"Hello", "Test1", "Test2", "Goodbye", "More?", "Qwerty"}` and, say I want to divide by 4, it *should* return `{ {"Hello", "Test1", "Test2", "Goodbye"}, {"More?", "Qwerty"} }` but it doesn't.

The whole class (the method I want to improve is the / operator, but if you see anything else I can work on please point it out) (I know barely any of it is commented. Sorry about that, didn't expect anyone else to see this code aside from me.):

```
public struct StringCollection
{
    private String[] value;

    public StringCollection(params String[] s)
    {
        this.value = s;
    }

    public StringCollection(StringCollection current, String ad)
    {
        if (current.value == null) {
            current.value = new String[0] { };
        }
        this.value = new String[current.value.Length+1];
            for (int i=0; i<this.value.Length; i++)
            {
                try {
                    this.value[i] = current[i];
                } catch {
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.value[this.value.Length-1] = ad;
    }
    public StringCollection(StringCollection x, params StringCollection[] y)
    {
        this.value = x.value;
        for (int j=0;j<y.Length;j++)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<y[j].value.Length;i++)
            {
                this += y[j][i];
            }
        }
    }

    public static StringCollection[] operator /(StringCollection x, int y)
    {
        StringCollection[] result = null;
        if (((int)x.value.Length/y) == ((double)x.value.Length)/y)
            result = new StringCollection[y];
        else
            result = new StringCollection[y+1];
        for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<((int)x.value.Length/y);i++)
            {
                result[j] += x.value[i+(int)((x.value.Length/y)*j)];
            }
        }
        if (((int)x.value.Length/y) != ((double)x.value.Length)/y)
        {
                            // This is the part that isn't working.
            for (int i=0;i<(((int)x.value.Length/y)*result[0].value.Length)-x.value.Length;i++) 
            {
                result[result.Length-1] += x.value[i+((result[0].value.Length)*result.Length-2)];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public String this[int index]
    {
        get {
            return this.value[index];
        }
        set {
            this.value[index] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

What it does is basically takes your array (single array) and splits it into a bunch of arrays that are the same size, then it adds on the remainder in a new array at the end.

Comment: This is not the place for this particular question perhaps you are seeking a `Code Review`

Comment: Rather than make me figure out what you are doing with the `/` operator, can you give a brief explanation of the intent?

Comment: @DJKRAZE this might get closed at code review also, because he's asking about a specific problem. Code review generally presumes working code and asks how best to refactor. This code is _not_ working, and he wants to know how to fix it.

Comment: That said, this question is also not suited for Stack Overflow as asked. To be a valid SO question, we need to see specifically what the problem is and how to reproduce it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: hoping the OP will explain the `/` operator's use.

Comment: I put it at the end but I feel like I wasn't clear enough. The idea is that if I have a `StringCollection sc { "Hello", "Goodbye", "Tata", "Foo" }` and did `sc/4`, the result would be `StringCollection[] sc2 { {"Hello"}, {"Goodbye"}, {"Tata"}, {"Foo"} }`. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Winderps: you can probably reduce the amount of code you have shown. Keep the `StringCollection` construction and the `/` operator method.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, and removed unnecessary code, hope that helps.

Comment: I noticed that as well only he would know about his specific problem since he wrote it..

Comment: Side note: your strategy for growing array is potentially very bad if you ever plan to call it more than couple times.

Comment: Whats the logic for your division? How can you ask the question "How many times will x go into y?" with strings the same as you do in integer division?

Comment: @kbzombie: I think what you mean is why would I need to (correct me if I'm wrong). So, say for example, that you have 50 users with passwords and authentication keys all in an array like {user, pass, auth, etc}, and you want to iterate through all of them for some reason, it stands to reason, that if you split them into groups of 3, you could do so much much easier.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov, your strategy for growing the array is potentially bad (also, what's the use of the try catch ? ). You should use a `List<string>` instead of `string[]` since it already automatically grows...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov and digEmAll: thank you for your input, that is really quite helpful. Also, the use of the catch is if they input a blank StringCollection, so it doesn't throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Winderps: actually it's bad practice to swallow exceptions or use try-catch in control flow (just to give one reason, try-catch is a really expensive operation when catches an exception) so you should check the lengths of the arrays and avoid it ...

Comment: @digEmAll, just to clarify, it is the throwing and catching of exceptions that is expensive, not the `try`.

Comment: @pamphlet: correct, in fact I specified *"try-catch is expensive when catches an exception"* ;)

Comment: Why would you even write this `StringCollection` class? It looks like a non-standard, clunky, and inefficient implementation of something that already exists and works quite well: `List<string>`. You can write a static helper method to do the "divide" operation. I don't question your need for that grouping operation, but overloading "/" to express it is, in my opinion, a terrible design decision. Call it something like `GetGroupsOf` or something like that. And the return value would be of type `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: @JimMischel To be completely honest, I still consider myself an absolute beginner in C# (after like 4 years) (not that I don't know how to do things, more that I don't know how to do them _properly_ and _efficiently_) And this was more a practice exercise than something I actually plan on implementing. I just recently started using operator overloading and this was a good way to practice it. At any rate, yes you are correct, thank you for you input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your question isn't really related to loops at all, or at least loops are only addressed in your code. You should have titled this differently.

Secondly your array adding/removing could be improved; i.e. adding 1 to array size every time and removing 1 then re-copying the entire array every time is a time-sink.

Now onto your question, your code should basically look like this:

```
//Make your return array
int retLen = x.Length / y;      

//Add space for the remainder
if(x.Length % y != 0)
  retLen++;

var ret = new StringCollection[retLen];

//Reusing variables is a good way to save memory, but watch naming conventions as this can be confusing
retLen = 0;

var tempCollection = new StringCollection();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
  tempCollection = new StringCollection(tempCollection, x[i]);

  if(i % y == 0 || i == x.Length - 1)
  {
    ret[retLen++] = tempCollection;
    tempCollection = new StringCollection();
    retLen = 0;
  }    
}

return ret;
```

I really don't like that you don't have a Add function in this struct, just so we're clear. the `tempCollection = new StringCollection(tempCollection, x[i]);` is f$*kin' TERRIBLE when it comes to time CPU time to create all those new objects.

Pretty sure you'll need to tweak that to make sure all items are entered properly, but that was a first attempt, so ... meh o.O Figured since no one was actually going to answer you I'd take the time.

EDIT: Found a bug, forgot to set retLen back to 0 when adding to ret

Comment: Thank you for this! Wow, compared to your code, mine looks like spaghetti. I will use this from now on. :D